# NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question. When I use Ajax.Actionlink and reload part of the page in PartialView my jquery invokes don't work. For example some simple functions like applying some plugin to "select" element.

I don't think there is code required since this is generic question.

So I am interested do I have to somehow reapply the same function call after I run Ajax.ActionLink..

Maybe OnComplete after OnSuccess code I can reapply my plugin to select element?

Simple Ajax.Actionlink:

```
            @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", MVC.Customer.GetCustomerNotes(customer.Id), new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        UpdateTargetId = "PopupHolder",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        OnSuccess = "ShowPopup('" + customer.LastName + " " + customer.FirstName + " notes')"
                    }
                    , new { @class = "icon-file", title = "View Notes" })
```

The call of jquery plugin is defined in normal jquery:

```
$(function(){
$('select').select2();
});
```

The point is this plugin doesn't work(doesn't append to select) in popup aka after ajax call of microsoft ajax.actionlink...

Answer (score 0):

Put $('select').select2(); in a script tag at the end of the markup in your partial view.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your plugin call executes once, after document was loaded the first time. But you should call this plugin after markup is changed, to make it work with new markup. So, you can either put this code in `<script>` tag in the partial view (as @SethMW mentioned in his answer):

```
<script>
    $('select').select2();
</script>
```

or use `OnSuccess` or `OnComplete` handlers for this javascript (as you mentioned in the question):

```
OnComplete = "$('select').select2();"
```

---

**UPD.** If there are many scenarios like this in your application, try to set global jQuery ajax handler [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) in the layout template. For example:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $('select').select2();
});
```

Comment: I have this thing in trillion scenarios like this, I need to find a solution to make it for for all globaly, for every partial view refresh, instead of putting them into all OnComplete lines.